# Accessing outer variable inside eventListener

Tags: javascript, scope, event-listener

In case of:

```
    var allBusiness = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    for (var i = 0; i < allBusiness.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(allBusiness[i]).addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log(allBusiness);
    });
}
```

This one logs `["one", "two", "three", "four"]`

However the following one where I try to log each value separately shows `undefined`:

```
    var allBusiness = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    for (var i = 0; i < allBusiness.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(allBusiness[i]).addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log(allBusiness[i]);
    });
}
```

why doesn't what log the corresponding names? and how to achieve that?

Comment: Just a suggestion but, try defining `allBusiness[i]` into a var before the console.log. no garuntees

Comment: @dave wouldn't `this` reference the element?

Comment: I misread, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is simple: i is no longer defined in the scope of the callback function you are passing through.

As for how, i think a good question to ask, what are you trying to achieve? You can just use this.

```
var allBusiness = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
for (var i = 0; i < allBusiness.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById(allBusiness[i]).addEventListener("click", function () {
        console.log(this.id);
    });
}
```

p.s. note: I do not think this is a good way to solve the problem, but it'll get what you want

Comment: As much as this doesn't answer what he _wants_, it does answer what he asked: _why?_

Comment: fair enough, i missed the how... editing :P